# How to point in direction of movement using MarkerView of Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using Mapbox android sdk for my map application, i want to use pointer icon('myIcon' in this case) which always points in the direction where user is moving.

I here is my code :

```
 public void addMarker(MapboxMap mapboxmap) {
// marker view options : setting location and icon
    MarkerViewOptions options = new MarkerViewOptions()
                                        .position(latLng)
                                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                                        .icon(myIcon);

    MarkerView view = options.getMarker();

// added marker on map                   
    mapboxMap.addMarker(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With marker views we don't expose a way to do this, and your only option is to adjust the marker rotation when the camera is rotated. A better solution would be to use runtime styling and a symbol layer. An example of this can be found in our [demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/SymbolLayerActivity.java). To ensure that the marker always points in the correct direction you can use the [icon-rotation-alignment](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-icon-rotation-alignment) property and set it to `map`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for help @cammace!

Answer (score 0):

Setting rotation on location update {like setRotation(angle_you_want_to_set)} worked of me.

Example :

```
public void addMarker(MapboxMap mapboxmap, float angle) {
// marker view options : setting location and icon
    MarkerViewOptions options = new MarkerViewOptions()
                                        .position(latLng)
                                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
//set angle of ration for icon
                                        .setRotation(angle)
                                        .icon(myIcon);

    MarkerView view = options.getMarker();

// added marker on map                   
    mapboxMap.addMarker(options);
    }
```